# Gutenberg Inspector Controls

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to make a simple Gutenberg block which implements `<InspectorControls>`, but I'm getting a React error no matter which I component I use.

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const {
    registerBlockType,
    RichText,
    AlignmentToolbar,
    BlockControls,
    InspectorControls,
    TextControl
} = wp.blocks;

registerBlockType( 'gutenberg-examples/example-04-controls-esnext', {
    title: __( 'Example: Controls (esnext)' ),
    icon: 'universal-access-alt',
    category: 'layout',
    attributes: {
        content: {
            type: 'array',
            selector: 'p',
        },
    },
    edit: props => {
        const {
            attributes: {
                content,
                alignment,
                text
            },
            focus,
            className,
            setFocus
        } = props;

        const onChangeContent = newContent => {
            props.setAttributes( { content: newContent } );
        };

        const onChangeAlignment = newAlignment => {
            props.setAttributes( { alignment: newAlignment } );
        };

        const onChangeText = newText => {
            props.setAttributes( { text: newText } );
        };

        return (
            <div>
                {
                    !! focus && (
                        <InspectorControls>
                            <AlignmentToolbar
                                value={ alignment }
                                onChange={ onChangeAlignment }
                            />
                            <TextControl
                                label='Additional CSS Class'
                                value={ text }
                                onChange={ onChangeText }
                            />
                        </InspectorControls>
                    )
                }
                <RichText
                    className={ className }
                    style={ { textAlign: alignment } }
                    onChange={ onChangeContent }
                    value={ content }
                    focus={ focus }
                    onFocus={ setFocus }
                    />
            </div>
        );
    },
    save: props => {
        // ignore for now
    }
} );
```

I'm using the 'create-guten-block' development kit.

Error:

```
react-dom.min.3583f8be.js:162 Error: Minified React error #130; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at l (react-dom.min.3583f8be.js:12)
    at qc (react-dom.min.3583f8be.js:43)
    at K (react-dom.min.3583f8be.js:53)
    at n (react-dom.min.3583f8be.js:57)
    at react-dom.min.3583f8be.js:62
    at f (react-dom.min.3583f8be.js:130)
    at beginWork (react-dom.min.3583f8be.js:136)
    at d (react-dom.min.3583f8be.js:158)
    at f (react-dom.min.3583f8be.js:159)
    at g (react-dom.min.3583f8be.js:159)
```

Comment: How do you know it's the `InspectorControls` component? have you tried not minifying your build? have you considered asking on the gutenberg GH? Or the `create-guten-block` project? It's hard to tell if this is a general React usage issue or a GB usage issue, or something specific to `create-guten-block`

Comment: When I remove only the <InspectorControls> code the script does work fine.

Comment: [**here**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/324094/157889) you can find your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TextControl` is from `wp.components` not `wp.blocks`.

```
const {
    registerBlockType,
    RichText,
    AlignmentToolbar,
    BlockControls,
    InspectorControls,
} = wp.blocks;
const {
    TextControl
} = wp.components;
```

Changing that I was able to get your block to work fine instead of error in `Gutenberg 2.2.0`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, David. That worked! Working code for reference: https://gist.github.com/DannyCooper/911a460e60077104c72cc7f37e1f5ce0

Answer (score 5):

`InspectorControls` is deprecated as of v2.4

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/9ebb918176c1efd0c41561d67ea3273bae5d3d6a/docs/deprecated.md#L15

> wp.blocks.InspectorControls.* components removed. Please use wp.components.* components instead.

This is right at the top of your code:

```
const {
    registerBlockType,
    RichText,
    AlignmentToolbar,
    BlockControls,
    InspectorControls,
    TextControl
} = wp.blocks;
```

Specifically:

```
const {
    ...
    InspectorControls,
    ...
} = wp.blocks;
```

This is deprecated and won't work, as the deprecated doc on the Gutenberg repo says so:

> wp.blocks.InspectorControls.* components removed. Please use wp.components.* components instead.

Comment: I've changed it to this which I believe is correct (with reference to Gutenberg GH structure:

const {
 registerBlockType,
 RichText,
 InspectorControls
} = wp.blocks;
const {
 AlignmentToolbar,
 BlockControls,
 TextControl,
} = wp.components;

However, this section still seems to cause the script to break:

    {
     !! focus && (
      <InspectorControls>
       ...
      </InspectorControls>
     )
    },

Comment: Notice the first thing your script does, it imports `InspectorControls` from `wp.blocks`, GB deprecated that, it won't work, read the doc it says exactly what to use instead

Comment: Tom, apologies if if I’m completely misunderstanding. But doesn’t the documentation state that the controls have been moved to /components but InspectorControls itself is still /block ?

Comment: You still have InspectorControls in blocks, that's deprecated. For what to replace it with and be sure it's working, i would ask on github, that's *the* place for GB questions. It's not out of scope here, but the expertise isn't quite here yet as GB is new and in flux

Comment: in [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/304562/157889) you gonna find What's changed, and in [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/324094/157889) you can find a walk though

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how many people also got stuck here. There are 2 files you need to edit, if your folder structure for the plugin is as follows

```
my-guten-block
|-> /src
||-> block.js
|-> plugin.php
```

The `plugin.php` file you will need to add the dependency of `wp-editor` when enqueuing the script

```
const dependencies = array('wp-editor');

wp_enqueue_script( handle: 'my-guten-block',
                   src: plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'src/block.js',
                   dependencies)
```

Then you can add to the `block.js` file

`const { InspectorControls } = wp.editor`

And use as needed.