# Implement Panel Color Inspector Control in Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to implement Panel Color in the Inspector Control for a custom block but can't seem to figure it out. Below is the JSX code that attempts it. It renders the block, but when it's in focus, it encounters a [Minified React error #130](http://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]=).

```
const { registerBlockType, InspectorControls, PanelColor } = wp.blocks;

registerBlockType( 'test/test', {
    title: 'Test',
    icon: 'universal-access-alt',
    category: 'layout',

    edit( { attributes, className, setAttributes } ) {
        const { backgroundColor } = attributes;
        const onChangeBackgroundColor = newBackgroundColor => {
            setAttributes( { backgroundColor: newBackgroundColor } );
        };

        return (
            <div className={ className }>
            { !! focus && (
              <InspectorControls>
                <PanelColor
                  title={ 'Background Color' }
                  value={ backgroundColor }
                  onChange={ onChangeBackgroundColor }
                />
              </InspectorControls>
            ) }
          </div>
        );
    },
    save( { attributes, className } ) {
        const { backgroundColor } = attributes;
        return (
            <div className={ className }>
            </div>
        );
    },
} );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many `wp.blocks.*` controls have been moved to `wp.editor.*` (see [release notes](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/v2.9.2/docs/reference/deprecated.md#310)).

Specifically `wp.blocks.InspectorControls` is now `wp.editor.InspectorControls` - you'll need to change the first line of your code.

*Note: `registerBlockType` is still imported from `wp.blocks.*` iirc.*

As a side note, I've also found that the `focus &&` trick no longer required as GB automatically displays the InspectorControls when the block is focused.

Comment: this is true, thanks that helps alot. but now most of `wp.blocks` moved to `wp.components` such as the question related `ColorPalette`

Comment: Since WP v5.2 wp.editor.* is deprecated and wp.blockEditor.* should be used. See https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/04/09/the-block-editor-javascript-module-in-5-2/

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to give you a walk through to the point, because I struggled too :)

First import the `InspectorControls`

```php
const { InspectorControls } = wp.editor;
```

then import components such as `ColorPalette`

```php
const { ColorPalette } = wp.components;
```

In order to save the state you have to define an attribute:

```php
attributes: {
    // To storage background colour of the div
    background_color: { 
        type: 'string', 
        default: 'red', // Default value for newly added block
    },           
    // To storage the complete style of the div that will be 'merged' with the selected colors
    block_style: { 
        selector: 'div', // From tag a
        source: 'attribute', // binds an attribute of the tag
        attribute: 'style', // binds style of a: the dynamic colors
    }
},
```

Then at the `edit` function... Define the `onChangeColorHandler` and a variable to hold the changed value in the **JSX**, because of course you can't from the css.

In the `return` part return an array of two elements `[]` the `Inspector` and the rendered `div` in the editor

```php
edit: function( props ) {

    var background_color = props.attributes.background_color // To bind button background color

    // Style object for the button
    // I created a style in JSX syntax to keep it here for
    // the dynamic changes
    var block_style = props.attributes.block_style // To bind the style of the button
    block_style = {
        backgroundColor: background_color,
        color: '#000',
        padding: '14px 25px',
        fontSize: '16px', 
    }

    //
    // onChange event functions
    //
    function onChangeBgColor ( content ) {
        props.setAttributes({background_color: content})
    }

    // Creates a <p class='wp-block-cgb-block-gtm-audio-block'></p>.
    return [
        <InspectorControls>
            <label class="blocks-base-control__label">background color</label>
            <ColorPalette // Element Tag for Gutenberg standard colour selector
                onChange={onChangeBgColor} // onChange event callback
            />
        </InspectorControls>
        ,
        <div className={ props.className } style={block_style}>
            <p>— Hello from the backend.</p>
        </div>
    ];
},
```

** FINALLY: ** the save method, just create variable for the style and give the rendered `div` the JSX style of that value.

```php
save: function( props ) {

    var block_style = {
        backgroundColor: props.attributes.background_color
    }
    return (
        <div style={block_style}>
            <p>— Hello from the frontend.</p>
        </div>
    );
},
```

> [here is a complete gist of the file](https://gist.github.com/BiskremMuhammad/cf9c4a882e2f373d13602766e1867b60#file-gutenberg-block-development-simple-div-with-background-color-change-from-inspector-js)

Answer (score 0):

`PanelColor` has been deprecated, use `PanelColorSettings` instead:

```
const {
    PanelColorSettings,
    …
} = wp.editor;

…

edit: (props) => {
    …
    return (
        …
        <InspectorControls>
            <PanelColorSettings
            title={ 'Background Color' }
            colorSettings={[{
              value: backgroundColor,
              onChange: onChangeBackgroundColor,
              label: __('Background Color')
            }]}
          />
      </InspectorControls>
      …
```